# Why is my React component always mounted, unmounted and mounted again?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

I'm studying React hooks and I noticed a strange behavior, can someone explain to me why?

The component is mounted, sets the state to the initial value and then is unmounted, to be mounted and updated again!!!

I understand that every update the component is re-rendered, but why is the componentWillUnmounted method (in this case useEffect's return) called?

I had the same strange behavior when I was studying class component and life cycles...

root component

```
    function App() {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            {visible && <UseEffect />}
            <button onClick={() => setVisible((visible) => !visible)}>
                Show/Hide
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

child component

```
const UseEffect = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    //didMounted
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Cp Mounted');

        //didUnmounted
        return () => {
            console.log('Cp UnMounted');
        };
    }, []);

    //didUpdate
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Cp Updated');
    });

    //with state
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Change 'counter');
    }, [counter]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{counter}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

output browser console

[image]

This is driving me crazy!!! Please someone know explain why this happen?

Thx

Comment: which version of react are you using?

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia vesion 18.0.0

Comment: there has been some changes related to mounting in react version 18.[check react docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable `<StrictMode></StrictMode>` in index.js file you won't get component unmounted and mounted again, the [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) make sure there was not bugs while rendering components twice, and that's why you see the mounting behaviour

[Check out sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-lake-353djv)

Comment: Thx! This work but, by disabling strict mode can cause any future issues?
And can this initial double rendering cause problems too or is it just annoying?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It is only present in dev mode while disabled in production